# How long does Azure IoT Central Store telemetric data?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I would like to know how long my telemetry data will be stored by IoT Central.
Thanks for every answer in advanced!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pricing page states that the data retention is 30 days.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/iot-central/
[image]

Answer (score 1):

30 days (currently).

The IoT Central quotas and limits is the best location to refer to this information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/concepts-quotas-limits